# Find 3 numbers a, b, c each from 3 arrays that sum to a given number T?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, sum, binary-search

This is an interview question and the complexity required is O(nlogn).I have implemented a O(n^2 logn) solution.
Its given that the solution exists.
Kindly provide the pseudo-code of your solution too.
Thanks.

Code Snippet of my O(n^2 logn) solution :

```
triplet SumOf3(vector<int> A, vector<int> B, vector<int> C, int T)
{
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    sort(B.begin(), B.end());
    sort(C.begin(), C.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(), ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); ++j) {
            int s = A[i] + B[j];
            int ind = int(lower_bound(C, C + C.size(), T - s) - C.begin());
            if (s + C[ind] == T) {
                triplet ans;
                ans.a = A[i];
                ans,b = B[j];
                ans.c = C[ind];
                return ans;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mistaken. It was not an interview. It was an exam on combinatorial calculus.

Comment: what is 'num' in if(Arrays.binarySearch(C, num - sum) > 0) {

Comment: and i think you're right.

Comment: @SariRahal, num is T. my mistake. edited.

Comment: Note: Could assume the arrays are sorted for if they were not it is O(n * log2 n) to sort them.

Comment: Hmmm the `Arrays.binarySearch(C, T - sum)` seems wasteful as code knows from the previous search to not have to search the entire `C`.

Comment: Kindly see my edited question.Apology for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question should the function return  a boolean value or that three numbers.
I think 3 for loops should be nested and why do you search number T in array C.
You just need to see if the sum equals to number T and one another thing in C we don't have anything like .length.
Here is an example :

```
int temp;
for(int i = 0;i<A.length;i++)
  for(int j = 0;j<B.length;j++)
    for(int k = 0;k<C.length;k++)
        temp = A[i]+B[j]+C[k];
        if(temp==T)
        return true;
return false;
```